# working with R1C1, indirect formula and cell address

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the following R1CI formula

```
"=SUM(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Summary'!""&CELL(""address"",E70)):INDEX(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Summary'!""&CELL(""address"",E70)&"":""&CELL(""address"",P70)),MATCH(R2C2,INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Summary'!E3:P3""),0)))"
```

However, the cells E70 & P70 in the formula are posted as 'E70' & 'P70'. Thereby causing the formula to fail.

Does anyone know how I can remove the inverted commas.

Thank you

Comment: I've worked it out. For any one interested it's; [code] lOffset = 70 "=SUM(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Summary'!""&CELL(""address"",R[" & lOffset - i.Row & "]C5)):INDEX(INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Summary'!""&CELL(""address"",R[" & lOffset - i.Row & "]C5)&"":""&CELL(""address"",R[" & lOffset - i.Row & "]C16)),MATCH(R2C2,INDIRECT(""'""&R2C3&"" Summary'!E3:P3""),0)))"
      
       lOffset = lOffset + 1 [/code]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `E70` and `P70`,

use `R70C5` and `R70C16`

Comment: thanks CLR. I have done this, but i has  now locked Columns E & P. So now I  have $E$70 & $P$70. Therefore the formula is no longer coping down correctly

Comment: If you want it to use the current row (i.e. the row you're writing to), instead of locking it to row 70, use `RC5` and `RC16`